# How do i send a success status code to the front end using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, http-status-code-500

I have recently started using node.js as my backend and I have successfully posted data to the database, the problem that I am facing now is telling the front end that data has been successfully saved. Below is my user route with all the things I have tried commented out.

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { IUser } from '../models/user.model';
const User = require('../models/user.model');
// import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

const userRouter = Router();

userRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.json('This is the user route');
})

userRouter.post("/register", (req, res: any, next) => {


    const user: IUser = new User({

        email: res.email,
        firstName: res.firstName,
        lastName: res.lastName,
        password: res.password,
        displayName: res.displayName,
        cellNumber: res.cellNumber,
    });

    user.save()
        .then((result: any) => {

            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Successfully created a new user!',
                result: result
            });
            // res.sendCode(201);
            // console.log(res);
            // res.status(201).send("User has been successfully created");
            //return 'User has been successfully created';

            // return Object({ message: "User has been successfully created" });

            // return res.status(201).send({
            //     message: "User has been successfully created",
            //     statusCode: 201
            // })

            // return res;

        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })


    // bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    //     .then((hash: string) => {

    //         const user = new User({

    //             email: req.body.email,
    //             firstName: req.body.firstName,
    //             lastName: req.body.lastName,
    //             password: hash,
    //             displayName: req.body.displayName,
    //             cellNumber: req.body.cellNumber,
    //         });

    //         user.save()
    //             .then((res: any) => {

    //                 res.status(201).json({
    //                     message: 'Successfully created a new user!',
    //                     result: res
    //                 });

    //             })
    //             .catch((err: any) => {
    //                 debugger;
    //                 res.status(500).json({
    //                     error: Error
    //                 })
    //             })
    //     })

})

export default userRouter;
```

which I then export to the server.ts file which is below

```
import express = require('express');
//import cors from 'cors';
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
import { Router } from 'express';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import "dotenv/config"

//routes
import userRouter from './routes/user.routes';

//Create a new express instance
const app: express.Application = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.send('Hello World');

});

// //get router
// var router = express.Router();

//Database
mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}`,
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB")
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("Connection to Database has failed")
    })


var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
    methods: '*'
};



const routes = Router();

export default routes;

app.use(routes);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use("/user", userRouter);



routes.use('/user', userRouter);
routes.use(cors(corsOptions));

//use cors middleware
// router.use(cors(options));

app.listen(3000, function () {

    console.log('App is listening on port 3000!');

})
```

What is strange is that when I set breakpoints and analyse the res file, i can see the data that I would have posted from the front end. But the front end gets the 500 status code instead of the 201 that I want to be sending, even though it passes right over that code. I have googled the keys of my keyboard for three days now. So I am at a loss now.

**All The latest changes can be found in the GitLab repository below**
https://gitlab.com/ShanahJr/SuperiorBallers

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make use of `res` variable provided by `express`.
Example -

```
module.exports.updateData = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const data = await Editor.edit(req.body.query);

        res.status(200).json({ "status": true, "result": 'Edit successful!' })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(200).json({ "status": false, "result": "Request Failed!" })
    }
}
```

This statement - `res.status(200).json({ "status": true, "result": 'Edit successful!' })`

Nowadays, express also suggests using `res.sendStatus(200)` over `res.status(200)`

You can lookup for status codes [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

Comment: I am still facing the same issue

Comment: What is the error you're getting inside the try-catch block?

Comment: Internal server error. I am not being given any more informatrion

Comment: It is only obvious that you're getting a 500 internal server error. It is because your code is failing and you have added the following code in the catch block.
```
.catch((err: any) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })```


So what you can do is add an error interceptor in the frontend application to deal such error codes your server is sending.

WHile here the error is because your code is failing

Comment: I have added the error interceptor. It is not giving me any information though

Comment: You might wanna share the github repo so that we can debug

Comment: When trying to save() does your table get updated?

Comment: Can you console log the err in your catch block and share it?

Comment: @SrinathNilatech That used to be the case but now it no longer saves. I have chanegd too much. But when it did save I would still get the internal server error in the console

Comment: @EmreDalkiran I am failing to log the error but when I add a break point and hover over the error, it tells me that the required values are null, I believe that is the current problem we are facing

Answer (score -1):

Use `res.status(201).send()`, `res.status().json` usually gets blocked by http rules especially when you activate https

Comment: This is complete nonsense.